# Use a value after hash in the URL in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, url

i know that this isn't easily possible since the url after the # is never sent to the server.

However...

I have a page that shows 16 database results. There is a load more button which loads the next 16. I am trying to come up with a way that if the user leaves the current page, and goes back it then i can fetch the value after the hash and use that as a LIMIT claus value.

So, www.domain.com goes to www.domain.com/#1

My new results are fetched via ajax and i know you cant modify a URL with javascript without reloading the page.

Is there a way i can take the number after the # in the URL, and use it in PHP?

I dont mind a bit of hackery and getting it with javascript etc.

Thanks!

Comment: When the page loads, allow PHP send a blank page (no results) for structure, and have Javascript issue the initial request based on the hash, if unavailable, then request the first page, parse and display whichever.

Comment: so dont use hash? `?page=1` etc

Comment: It's not a "hash" it's an "anchor" or "fragment". Its use is entirely internal to the browser, so it is not sent with the HTTP request. If you want to send information in the page url you need to use the query string like Dagon has suggested. Some clientside javascript applications make use of the anchor, but that is only possible because javascript runs within the browser and is aware of the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

As you said the hash is never sent to the server. The only way to read or set the hash is using javascript.

```
document.location.hash.substring(1) //remove the starting hash
```

If you want to send it to the server you'll have to do an AJAX request. With jQuery:

```
$('#content').load('loadContent.php?limit='+document.location.hash.substring(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the hash value on load. If exists load your ajax:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash){
        yourajaxfunction(window.location.hash.substr(1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to work this.

The results are loaded each time with ajax so no page reload is needed.

I have wrapped my load more button in an A link which has a href starting off with #1.

When the new results are loaded, i change that link href to a generated pageIndex++ number.

When a user visits the page and only if the URL contains a fragment, i then convert that fragment to a ? and then redirect.

From this i can then use a PHP GET function.

Example:

```
// First get the page URL and split it via # signs
var parts = location.href.split('#');

// now we run a check on the URL and see how many 'parts' there are
if(parts.length > 1)
{
  var params = parts[0].split('?');
  var mark = '?';
  if(params.length > 1)
  {
    mark = '&';
  }
  location.href = parts[0] + mark + 'page=' + parts[1];
}
```